# How to get map tiles to line up nicely?

Tags: xna, 2d

When I first created my code, there were quite a few cases where I would get horizontal and vertical gaps between tiles when displayed. I put this down to rounding issues with `float`s and just moved on to other things. Now that I've revisited the issue, I can't seem to get it working properly, even after trying my hardest to eliminate places where this sort of issue might happen. It seems to only happen when I place the camera at certain positions, which is why I think it's likely to be a `float` issue. If anyone could help me with the correct way to draw the tile layout, it'd be much appreciated.

This is my drawing method for the map:

```
public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    var topLeft = Camera.ScreenCoordinateToWorld(new Vector2(0, 0));
    // Readjust the position of the topLeft element so we get the actual 
    // drawing position for the tile here
    topLeft = new WorldCoordinate(topLeft.X - 1, topLeft.Y - 1, 
                                  -TileSize / 2, -TileSize / 2);
    var topLeftDrawPosition = topLeft.DrawPosition;
    var screenWidthInTiles = Game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / TileSize + 1;
    var screenHeightInTiles = Game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / TileSize + 1;

    for (var y = topLeft.Y; y <= topLeft.Y + screenHeightInTiles; y++)
    {
        for (var x = topLeft.X; x <= topLeft.X + screenWidthInTiles; x++)
        {
            if (x < 0 || y < 0 || y >= MapData.Count || x >= MapData[y].Count)
            {
                // Ignore out of range tiles to avoid exceptions
                continue;
            }

            var tile = MapData[y][x];
            var drawPosition = topLeftDrawPosition + 
                               new Vector2((x - topLeft.X)*TileSize, 
                                           (y - topLeft.Y)*TileSize);
            Tileset[tile].Draw(spriteBatch, drawPosition);
        }
    }

    base.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);
}
```

Broken:

[image: Screenshot of broken rendering]

Semi-working:

[image]

Comment: Is anti-aliasing enabled with your tile graphics?  If so, try disabling it just in case the edges aren't at 100% opacity.  In particular your water (blue) tiles are responsible for this hunch (see the dark area gradually disappearing along the bottom, starting from the left, of each of these tiles).

Comment: @Randolf: How would I check that? I'm not specifically turning on AA though.

Comment: If they're .png files, your graphics program might have this turned on by default (this is the case with Adobe Photoshop, so in that case you'd need to make sure there is no transparency in your layer -- experiment with white and black filled layers below it to see if the white or black bleed through, if they do then you'll have confirmation that you have transparency in your tile).  _Your game looks interesting, by the way._

Comment: The keywords that will be of interest to you here are Alpha-blending, Opacity, Anti-aliasing, and Transparency.

Comment: @Randolf: Yes, they are PNG's. I'll check this in a second (I used GIMP by the way), but as a sidenote, I had a bright idea before you started commenting. I just 'fixed' it by rendering the tiles to a `RenderTarget2D` then rendering the result as a single large image.

Comment: @Randolf: I couldn't find anything in GIMP's export settings about anything like that, and the image looks fine there. I think it may be getting mangled by the camera transform. The two-pass solution seems to be working well though, so I think I'll just stick with that and post it as an answer when I work out a few positioning bugs.

Comment: I didn't know from looking at your Question that you were rendering in 3D (so I assumed 2D due to the look of the graphics) -- lighting, view angle, and whatnot can have these types of effects on 3D graphics.  Switching to 2D in your case makes a lot more sense (you can still have 3D characters running around on top of your 2D backgrounds) and seems like the right solution to me.

Comment: @RandolfRichardson let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1126/discussion-between-matthew-scharley-and-randolf-richardson)

Comment: You could look at TiledLib's source (http://tiledlib.codeplex.com/) to see how they've done it, I never had rendering problems with it, and it's quite efficient.

Comment: Can you show the spritesheet?

Comment: @bobobobo: [Sure, here.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19145581/map_tileset.png) I know that the spritesheet is poorly done because I blew up a smaller one to get the size I wanted. There's a little bleed between the squares which explains the vertical lines being shown on both screenshots. It's the horizontal black lines that I'm interested in with this question.

Comment: @bobobobo: On a whim, I double checked. There is a tiny amount of transparency on the 80th pixel. I went back in time to before I did my fix and tried patching up those pixels, but still no luck, so the black lines aren't caused by transparency.

Comment: It does in fact seem to be something to do with the spritesheet. A fully whited out sprite sheet works perfectly, however if I simply white out a single square, then it goes back to showing lines. No idea what could be causing this, but my solution seems to work, and if the slight overhead of the two-pass rendering gets too much, then I'll address it then.

Comment: I had this problem a while ago, I solved it by just rounding the camera position to the nearest intiger

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One method I've discovered to fix this is to use a two-pass approach; first render the tiles onto a texture, then render the texture in the correct place. This seems to be mildly more expensive, as you'd expect, but does the job perfectly.

```
public override void LoadContent()
{
    MapSprite = new RenderTarget2D(Game.GraphicsDevice, ScreenWidthInTiles * TileSize, ScreenHeightInTiles * TileSize, true, Game.GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Format, DepthFormat.Depth24);
    MapSpriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(Game.GraphicsDevice);

    base.LoadContent();
}

public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    var topLeft = Camera.ScreenCoordinateToWorld(Vector2.Zero);
    // Readjust the position of the topLeft element so we get the actual drawing position for the tile here
    var topLeftTile = new WorldCoordinate(topLeft.X - 1, topLeft.Y - 1, -TileSize / 2, -TileSize / 2);
    Vector2 drawPosition;

    Game.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(MapSprite);
    Game.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

    MapSpriteBatch.Begin();

    for (var y = topLeftTile.Y; y <= topLeftTile.Y + ScreenHeightInTiles; y++)
    {
        for (var x = topLeftTile.X; x <= topLeftTile.X + ScreenWidthInTiles; x++)
        {
            if (x < 0 || y < 0 || y >= MapData.Count || x >= MapData[y].Count)
            {
                // Ignore out of range tiles to avoid exceptions
                continue;
            }

            var tile = MapData[y][x];
            drawPosition = new Vector2((x - topLeftTile.X)*TileSize,
                                        (y - topLeftTile.Y)*TileSize);
            Tileset[tile].Draw(MapSpriteBatch, drawPosition);
        }
    }

    MapSpriteBatch.End();
    Game.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

    // Render the result into the right place. First push the sprite up into the top left corner
    drawPosition = Camera.Position.DrawPosition - Game1.ScreenCentre - 
                    // The account for the offset of the camera
                    topLeft.Offset -
                    // And account for centering issues
                    new Vector2(TileSize*1.5f);
    spriteBatch.Draw(MapSprite, drawPosition, null, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 1.0f);

    base.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);
}
```

Comment: +1 because you posted a working solution to your problem (instead of just abandoning your question) -- hopefully this will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the TEXTURE WRAP mode is wrong.  You want to set it to CLAMP.  See [Texture address mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.textureaddressmode.aspx).

Comment: Where do you set this so that I can try it out? You just linked to the enumeration, but not where it is used.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I may be setting it incorrectly though. I'm using XNA 4.0, if you can advise how I should be setting this, then that would be good.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens because you are working with Vector2, this is, float values. So when XNA draws a sprite in a non integer coordinate, tends to adjust it by antialiasing the sprite.

To fix this, just make sure you convert your floats to integers before drawing it:

```
        var drawPosition = topLeftDrawPosition + 
                           new Vector2((int)((x - topLeft.X)*TileSize), 
                                       ((int) (y - topLeft.Y)*TileSize));
```

Regards